# How to get age from Google sign in?

Tags: android

I am making an android application that allows users to sign up using Google. I want to get age of user using his account

I found code to get name, Id, photo etc.

But i din find code to get age.

Can someone help me

Comment: AFAIK you cant get age directly..but you can get Birthdate and then count age

Comment: ya how to get bithdate

Comment: i think google not giving birthdate too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get User's Birthdate & Gender using Google Sign-In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234762/get-users-birthdate-gender-using-google-sign-in-android)